# how to pass two functions to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass two functions yet not working. Here is my attempt

> ChildComponent.js

```
render(
  let val = -1
    return(

<div>
     <Button onClick={this.props.handelSecondClick} >second button click</Button>
     <Button onClick={this.props.handelFirstClick} >First button click</Button>
</div>
)
)
```

> App.js

```
this.state = {
   data: [1,2]
}

handelFirstClick(val){
   alert("first button clicked")
   let data = this.state.data
   data[0] = val

   this.setState({data})
}

handelSecondClick(val){
   alert("second button clicked")
   let data = this.state.data
   data[1] = val

   this.setState({data})
}


render(

   return(
   < ChildComponent onClick={this.handelSecondClick(val)} onClick={this.handelFirstClick(val)} 
   )
/>
)
```

Is it even possible to pass two functions? On child component, I am creating two buttons two handle the two methods separetly. How should I modify so that both functions are passed two the child component?

Comment: You must rename `childComponent` to `ChildComponent`, or [Babel will treat that as a string instead of as a variable](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwYwFglgNgJgwgewLYAcEDsCm6AuACDOKCEAawF4BvHSAZwDowBDdGTKAZUxA3mLIC-BdERIVqdRizZQAYhABOtHKMF4A9AD4gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.3). You also shouldn't mutate the state directly.

Comment: You are trying to define onclick two times! That'll not work

Comment: how should i define once and at the same time pass two functions

Comment: Also, you can do like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v6jhh2 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 different functions.

Also you have missed out on binding these functions. Either use arrow functions or bind method.

```
< ChildComponent value={val}
handleSecondClick={() => this.handelSecondClick(val)} 
handleFirstClick={()=> this.handelFirstClick(val)} 
/>
```

You can access it via

```
this.props.handleSecondClick(this.props.value)
this.props.handleFirstClick(this.props.value)
```

Comment: Maybe no need arrow function in this case. Because he doesn't use params here.

Comment: if possible could you please update ur answer as if val is passed to the function

Comment: it says val is undefined

Comment: @toymoy is your val coming from the parent component? then ypu can pass it as a prop

Comment: @TamDc The arrow functions are required to ensure that `this` is bound correctly. The alternative would be to do `this.handelSecondClick = this.handelSecondClick.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send 2 different props for handling multiple clicks. Do something like

```
<ChildComponent firstClick={this.handleFirstClick.bind(this, val)} secondClick={this.handleSecondClick.bind(this, val)} />

handleFirstClick(val){...}
handleSecondClick(val){...}
```

In your child component, access them as

```
render(){
  return(
    <Button onClick={this.props.firstClick}>Button 1</Button>
    <Button onClick={this.props.secondClick}>Button 2</Button>
  )
}
```

Comment: if possible could you please update ur answer as if val is passed to the functio

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix would be

```
ChildComponent.js

render(
    return(

<div>
     <Button onClick={this.props.onFirstClick} >second button click</Button>
     <Button onClick={this.props.onSecondClick} >First button click</Button>
</div>
)
)
App.js

this.state = {
   data: [1,2]
}

handelFirstClick(){
   alert("first button clicked")
   let data = this.state.data
   data[0] = -1

   this.setState({data})
}

handelSecondClick(){
   alert("second button clicked")
   let data = this.state.data
   data[1] = -1

   this.setState({data})
}


render(
   return(
   < ChildComponent onSecondClick={this.handelSecondClick} onFirstClick={this.handelFirstClick} 
   )
/>
)
```

Also this is recommended to do a check on the onclick, if the props is actually function or not, otherwise it will throw an error.
Try

```
onFirstClick = () => {
 const {onFirstClick } = this.props;
 if (typeof onFirstClick === 'function') {
    onFirstClick();
 }
}
render(
    return(

<div>
     <Button onClick={this.onFirstClick} >second button click</Button>
     <Button onClick={this.onSecondClick} >First button click</Button>
</div>
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should you object-destructuring

App.js

```
render() {
  return(
   < ChildComponent func1={this.handelSecondClick} func2={this.handelFirstClick} />
  )
 }

ChildComponent .js

render() {
  const {func1, func2} = this.props
  return(
   <Button onClick={() => func1(val)} >second button click</Button>
   <Button onClick={() => func2(val)} >First button click</Button>
  )
 }
```

Comment: if possible could you please update ur answer as if val is passed to the functio

Comment: @toymoy my answer is already for passing `val` from childComponent. `func1={this.handleSecondClick}` is just assign address of function `handleSecondClick` to `func1`. So in `ChildComponent` you can call this function via `func1`

Answer (score -1):

There are two buttons in the component, you can pass both the functions as props in the component and add onClick method on buttons like:-

```
return(

<div>
     <Button onClick={this.props.function2} >second button click</Button>
     <Button onClick={this.props.function1} >First button click</Button>
</div>
)
```

and then in the component you can write as:-

```
< ChildComponent function1={this.handelFirstClick()} function2={this.handelSecondClick()} />
```

Hope this helps!